# How can I find all of the spaces in a sentence and replace ignore them?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm working on a JavaScript Hangman game and I need to print out the same number of dashes as the length of the word chosen at random. Iv'e done that but it also prints out a dash for the gaps that are in the sentence, so how can I ignore these spaces and only print out a dash for the letters in the sentence? Any help appreciated Thanks.

This is the code that prints the dashes out

```
for(var i = 0; i < sayings[randomSaying].length; i++)
{
   progress.innerHTML += "-";
}
```

Random Variable

```
var sayings = [
    "cash on the nail",
    "charley horse",
    "foul play",
    "bury the hatchet",
    "hands down",
    "if the cap fits",
    "mumbo jumbo",
    "see red",
    "stone the crows",
    "thick and thin",
]
sayings.toString();
var randomSaying = Math.floor(Math.random()*sayings.length);
```

Comment: A word chosen at random or a saying?

Comment: Question shows serious lack of research effort. This isn't a coding service and you are expected to try to research the basics yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` statement within your `for` loop. Also, don't use `innerHTML +=` because it causes the browser to have to re-parse the DOM over and over. Do this instead:

```
var hiddenSaying = "";
for(var i = 0; i < sayings[randomSaying].length; i++) {
    if (sayings[randomSaying].charAt(i) === ' ')
        hiddenSaying += " ";
    else
        hiddenSaying += "-";
}
progress.innerHTML = hiddenSaying;
```

Comment: You're right, it's just an opinion :)... will remove the comment. Personally I prefer to write less code to achieve the results ... sorry about it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to ignore the spaces, just replace the letters

```
progress.innerHTML = sayings[randomSaying].replace(/[a-z]+/g, "-");
```

Single line of code, all in one line, more efficient than looping ;)

Comment: `/\S+/g` or `/[^ ]+/g` would replace any non-space character. Or `/\w+/g` could be used if you just expect alphanumeric sayings.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer!

Comment: @4castle is right... but since your code is just showing `a-z` non Capital, I just put `a-z` in the regExp :). You can always tune that up to your needs.

Comment: @4castle Have you ever played hangman where you were supposed to fill in anything but letters?

Comment: @4castle I found this, in case you're interested :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243563/regex-vs-while-loops

Comment: @Barmar Yes I have. @DavidEspino That post says that regex is only faster if its using a `$` to anchor the search. In this case both the regex and loop would iterate the same amount and with the same speed. I agree though that the regex solution is nicer, but there's no efficiency involved.

Comment: I just noticed that the `+` is replacing each entire word with one dash `-` instead of replacing each individual letter. Remove the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, but I think you should take a look at this:

```
function randomSaying(sayingsArray){
  var p = sayingsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*(sayingsArray.length+1))];
  var d = p.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/./g, '&#8208;');
  return {phrase:p, dashes:d};
}
var obj = randomSaying(sayings);
// obj.phrase is phrase obj.dashes is dashes
```