# RegExp equivalent of array.indexOf( str )

Tags: javascript, regex, theory

Given a variable `str` containing a string value, are these two lines of code equivalent?

Line A:

```
if ( [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ].indexOf( str ) > -1 ) {
```

Line B:

```
if ( /^foo|bar|baz$/.test( str ) ) {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a version of JavaScript's String.indexOf() that allows for regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. He wants to convert indexOf to a regex, that question wants to call indexOf on a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. The pipes are including the `^` and `$` as alternatives. I'm not entirely clear on the syntax of JS's regular expressions, but if you're looking for `str` to contain only `foo`, or `bar`, or `baz`, use the expression `/^(foo|bar|baz)$/`. If you're looking to do something different, let me know and I'll try to clear it up.

Comment: I would like to achieve the behavior of Line A with Line B. (So, yes, I want to check if `str` is exactly one of those 3 values... )

Comment: Then yes, you want the regex I gave you. Alternately, if you don't need to capture /which/ value you match, you can use `/^(?:foo|bar|baz)$/`. The `?:` means 'don't bother remembering which one of these three matches', and it might be a bit faster

Comment: Could you explain why i have to group my `a|b|c`? How does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after the edit, they're still not equivalent since `test` will call `toString`. See:

```
var myItem = {toString: function() { return 'foo'; }};

['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].indexOf(myItem); // -1
/^(foo|bar|baz)$/.test(myItem); // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqu7D/

Even when they're string values (sorry, missed that) then they're *still* not equivalent because there are two different types of strings and `indexOf` uses strict equality/identity:

http://jsfiddle.net/HpCUY/

To make them truly equivalent, you can either call `.toString()` before using `indexOf`, or you can test `Object.prototype.toString.call(myItem) === '[object String]'` before using `test`.

Comment: Still they're different. Minitech gave you a few examples of things that B will catch that A will not, and see the regex I gave you for how to fix it.

Comment: @minitech Yes, but I mentioned in my question that `str` is a string value... It can't be an object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Sorry, missed that. I edited my answer again - they're [still not equivalent](http://jsfiddle.net/HpCUY/).

Comment: @minitech Uh... `:)` When I said "string value", I meant a value of the String type, not a String object... (String objects are useless, I would never use them... )

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I know :) But your question is tagged [tag:theory], and this is a possibility. jQuery does it too.

Comment: @minitech I guess "string value" is kind-of ambiguous - I should have said "value of type String". jQuery does what? Uses `new String()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5384/discussion-between-minitech-and-sime-vidas)

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not.

The method [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` if the item is not found in the array, or the position of the array if it *is* found in the array.

The method [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns `true` if the regex finds a match, and `false` if it doesn't.

If your regular expression was instead `/^(foo|bar|baz)$/`, then the function would be the same.

Comment: But why are the parens required?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Because `/^foo|bar$/` is `^foo` OR `bar$`, and thus would match "fools", and would also match "sandbar".