# JavaScript with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

```
var id = data.rslt;
var element = id.attr("crawlLocation");
if (element.indexOf("\\") != -1){
var toSearch = element.substring(0,element.lastIndexOf("\\"));
toSearch = "\"" + toSearch + "\"";
}
var stringContent = getInnerHTML('selectedCustodiansForIngestDiv');
if(stringContent.indexOf(toSearch) == -1){
  //This loop works fine on Firefox but not in IE8
}

function getInnerHTML(elmtId) {
var innerHTML = "";
if ($gElem(elmtId) != null) {
    innerHTML = document.getElementById(elmtId).innerHTML;
}
return innerHTML;
}
```

In the above code, the if condition with the `indexOf` method is not working as expected with IE8, but works fine with other browsers.

In IE8, even if the content in `toSearch` is found in the string `stringContent`, it goes inside the loop.

I am not sure whether the problem is with `indexOf` method or somewhere else in my code. Let me know a way to fix this! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just noticed on debugging that in IE, the toSearch variable is appearing as "\"D:\company\"" instead of "D:\company"(In mozilla and other browsers).

Any idea to overcome this?

Comment: can you try changing var element  to some other name e.g. var elem and see if it works

Comment: ya i tried it now. its not working even then

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on this [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) it's not available in IE8.

You can take a RegEx to account or see the fallbacks from MDN for:

- [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)
- [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf#Compatibility)

Comment: I tried pasting the indexOf implementation to the beginning of my script. But it didnt work even then.

Comment: how to do this with regex?

Comment: See this: [Is there a version of JavaScript's String.indexOf() that allows for regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/274094/612202)

Comment: Added this too `regexIndexOf`. No change in the results.

Comment: I can't reproduce this as I don't have IE 8. But with the right usage it should work (19 upvotes and an accept speak for themselves)

Comment: `if(stringContent.regexIndexOf(toSearch, 0) == -1){}` Is this correct after adding that regexIndexOf proptotype?

Comment: `element.indexOf("\\") != -1` should be replaced by `element.indexOf(/\\/) != -1` (as it is a handled as a RegEx). The other occurences should also be replaced.

Comment: I just noticed on debugging that in IE, the `toSearch` variable is appearing as "\"D:\\exterro\"" instead of "D:\\exterro"

Comment: Thats why its not finding the content. Any solution for this?