# JavaScript Regex find first not equal to

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I have, what I thought was, a simple regex to get anything not (letter), (number) or (%)

```
str.indexOf(/[^a-zA-Z0-9%]/);
```

However, I'm ALWAYS getting `-1`.

Here's an example `str`:

```
Check out this awesome video!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) doesn't take a regular expression as argument. Instead, it takes another `String` as argument. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

Comment: Why do you want to do this. Do you want to find a string? You want index of string? You want to replace something? As answered in the comments, `indexOf()` does not accept regex. Your requirements would narrow down other choices.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik I'm running it in a `while` and replacing each character individually with its hex equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put regex into indexOf. Use search instead.

See this for more info: [Is there a version of JavaScript's String.indexOf() that allows for regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Check out this awesome video!".replace(/./g,function(match){
  return '0x'+match.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
});
```

returns the hexadecimal representation of the string. If you want just convert alpha-numeric characters, replace the `.` in the regex by `\w`.