# Javascript: String search for regex, starting at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a javascript [string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) function that [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) a regex and it will start the search at the end?

If not, what is the fastest and/or cleanest way to search the index of a regex starting from the end?

example of regex:

```
/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?/gi
```

Comment: [Is there a version of JavaScript's String.indexOf() that allows for regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/274094/402037)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful and easier:

```
str.lastIndexOf(str.match(<your_regex_here>).pop());
```

Comment: This does work for the OP's RegExp; so it is correct. For clarity, though, note it won't work with all REs, namely ones with look ahead / behind. e.g. `'xhtml html'.match(/(?<=x)html/g)`. See Andreas's comment on the question for an implementation that handles this correctly.

Comment: This will throw an error if `match()` returns null. Add a conditional or use optional chain operator, e.g.: `str.lastIndexOf(str.match(<your_regex_here>)?.pop());`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this is suitable for you?

Javascript

```
function lastIndexOfRx(string, regex) {
    var match = string.match(regex);

    return  match ? string.lastIndexOf(match.slice(-1)) : -1;
}

var rx = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?/gi;

console.log(lastIndexOfRx("", rx));
console.log(lastIndexOfRx("<i>it</i><b>bo</b>", rx));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/asMua/)

And just for interest, this function vs the function that you choose to go with. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/lastindexof-regex)

This requires that you format your regex correctly for matching exactly the pattern you want and globally (like given in your question), for example `/.*(<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?)/i` will not work with this function. But what you do get is a function that is clean and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a reverse function like:

```
function reverse (s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}
```

and then use

```
var yourString = reverse("Your string goes here");
var regex = new Regex(your_expression);
var result = yourString.match(regex);
```

---

Another idea: if you want to search by word in reverse order then

```
function reverseWord(s) {
   var o = '';
   var split = s.split(' ');

  for (var i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += split[i] + ' ';
  return o;
}

var yourString = reverseWord("Your string goes here");
var regex = new Regex(your_expression);
var result = yourString.match(regex);
```

Comment: this is workable, but I want to know the index of the last occurrence of the regex directly. If there is no other faster method, then I'll probably take this as an answer

Comment: The `result` will returns the array, after that you'll need the last item of array.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas gave this from the comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/274094/402037

```
String.prototype.regexLastIndexOf = function(regex, startpos) {
    regex = (regex.global) ? regex : new RegExp(regex.source, "g" + (regex.ignoreCase ? "i" : "") + (regex.multiLine ? "m" : ""));
    if(typeof (startpos) == "undefined") {
        startpos = this.length;
    } else if(startpos < 0) {
        startpos = 0;
    }
    var stringToWorkWith = this.substring(0, startpos + 1);
    var lastIndexOf = -1;
    var nextStop = 0;
    while((result = regex.exec(stringToWorkWith)) != null) {
        lastIndexOf = result.index;
        regex.lastIndex = ++nextStop;
    }
    return lastIndexOf;
}
```

Which gives the functionality that I need, I tested my regex, and it is successful. So I'll use this

Comment: This was the answer years ago, but since javascript now supports some functionalities that are missing before, I updated the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you exactly want to search for. You can use `string.lastIndexOf` or inside the regexp to use `$` (end of the string).

**Update:**
try the regexp

```
/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?[\w\W]*$/gi
```

Comment: the problem with lastIndexOf is that regex are not included in the parameter, it only allows strings

Comment: well, the updated still returns the first instance of the regex using 
str.search(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?[\w\W]*$/gi);

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = text.match(/.*(<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?)/i);
if (m) {
    textFound = m[1];
    position = text.lastIndexOf(textFound);
}
```

Use .* to skip as much text as posible, capture the text found and search it with lastIndexOf

EDIT:

Well, if text is found, no need to search with lastIndexOf. m[0] contains the full coincidence (including all the initial padding), and m[1] the searched text. So position of found text is m[0].length - m[1].length

```
var m = text.match(/.*(<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?)/i);
if (m) {
    textFound = m[1];
    position = m[0].length - m[1].length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're looking for a string 'token', then you need the position of 'token' that has no other 'token' following until the end of the string.

So you should compose your regex something like that:

```
$token = 'token';
$re = "/(?:$token)[^(?:$token)]*$/";
```

This will find your 'token' where no further 'token' can be found until string end. The "(?:" grouping simply makes the group non-storing, slightly speeding up performance and saving memory.