# How do I extract JSON objects from a string and add them to an array?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to extract all JSON objects from a string randomly containing them and add them to an array.

Sample string:

```
"I was with {"name":"John"}{"name":"Anne"}{"name":"Daniel"} yesterday"`
```

how can i extract the JSON objects from this sample string?

Comment: Post your sample JSON string

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far... And some example string.

Comment: you can use JSON.parse(jsonString); where jsonString is a valid jsonstring

Comment: So you want to parse a string with semirandom content for any JSON objects in it?

Comment: Yes exactly! Then add those objects to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this is to use the str.search(regexp) function to find all parts of it that fulfill the JSON regex [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json). So you could write a function that searches over the string for regexp matches.

To actually extract the object from the string you could use [these two functions for the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr) and then loop over the string until all objects have been found.

```
var match      = str.match(regex);
var firstIndex = str.indexOf(match[0]);
var lastIndex  = str.lastIndexOf(match[match.length-1]);
var JSONobjects = [];
while( str.match(regex){

  //extract the wanted part.
  jsonObject = substr(str.indexOf(match[0],str.lastIndexOf(match[match.length1-]));

  //remove the already found json part from the string and continue
  str.splice(str.indexOf(match[0],str.indexOf(match[0] + jsonObject.length());

  //parse the JSON object and add it to an array.
  JSONobjects.push(JSON.parse(jsonObject));
}
```

Comment: Seems this should work. I will try it and get back to you later on how it went.

Comment: Im working on the specifics, but this currently just returns the starting index of the json object, what you need is to then work out how long the object is extract it. One solution could be to combine the first and last index of regex searches here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr this is also usefull.

Comment: actually you could do both the extracting and removal with splice.

Answer (score 3):

### This is what worked for me:

```js
const regex = /[{\[]{1}([,:{}\[\]0-9.\-+Eaeflnr-u \n\r\t]|".*?")+[}\]]{1}/gis;

function jsonFromString(str) {
  const matches = str.match(regex);
  return Object.assign({}, ...matches.map((m) => JSON.parse(m)));
}

console.log(jsonFromString(`Hi, my {"name": "Kingerious"} and my {"age": 14}`));
```

## Explanation

- Regex is first used to identify all valid JSON objects using `str.match()` function. It returns an array with all the objects.
- Then the array is looped over, parsed into JS objects and then merged to create one single object.

## Source

Regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167612/17152934

Comment: I am getting error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 6096 (line 1 column 6097)
`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the one that Kingerious made to make it recognize strings as well and to return an array of the objects instead of a single object with all of the other objects as its properties:

```js
const regex = /([{\[]{1}([,:{}\[\]0-9.\-+Eaeflnr-u \n\r\t]|".*?")+[}\]]{1}|["]{1}(([^(")]|\\")*)+(?<!\\)["]){1}/gis;

function jsonFromString(str) {
  const matches = str.match(regex);
  return matches.map((m) => JSON.parse(m));
}

console.log(jsonFromString(`some text {"val}ue": "something:some{thing"} and "teststri\\"n{g" some more other text [{"testa": 5, "testb": "t\\"\\"est6"}, {"testc": "1", "testd": "test45678"}, "teste", {"testf": {"testg": true, "testh": false}}] other extra added text {"somenumber": 14} "somestring"`)); //it can detect the json correctly even if you have other brackets or escaped quotation marks (\") inside of the strings.
```

Here is an even better version of this that uses a custom JSONParse() function to parse the JSON while also keeping Infinity, -Infinity, Undefined, NaN, and Null values:

```js
function JSONParse(JSONString, keepUndefined = true){
  let g = []; 
  let h = []; 
  let a = JSON.parse(JSONString.replace(/(?<="(?:\s*):(?:\s*))"{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}"(?=(?:\s*)[,}](?:\s*))/g, '"{{\\"{{$1}}\\"}}"').replace(/(?<="(?:\s*):(?:\s*))(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)(?=(?:\s*)[,}](?:\s*))/g, '"{{$1}}"'), function(k, v) {
    if (v === '{{Infinity}}') return Infinity;
    else if (v === '{{-Infinity}}') return -Infinity;
    else if (v === '{{NaN}}') return NaN;
    else if (v === '{{undefined}}') {g.push(k); if(keepUndefined){return v}else{undefined}};
    h.push(k); 
    return v;
  }); 
  g.forEach((v, i)=>{
    let b = Object.entries(a); 
    b[b.findIndex(b=>b[0]==v)]=[v, undefined]; 
    a=Object.fromEntries(b)
  }); 
  {
    let b = Object.entries(a); 
    !!b.filter(b=>String(b[1]).match(/^{{"{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}"}}$/)).forEach((v, i)=>{
      b[b.findIndex(b=>b[0]==v[0])]=[v[0], v[1].replace(/^(?:{{"{{)(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)(?:}}"}})$/g, '{{$1}}')]; 
      a=Object.fromEntries(b)
    })
  }; 
  return a; 
}

function JSONStringify(JSONObject, keepUndefined = false){
  return JSON.stringify(JSONObject, function(k, v) {
    if (v === Infinity) return "{{Infinity}}";
    else if (v === -Infinity) return "{{-Infinity}}";
    else if (Number.isNaN(v)) return "{{NaN}}";
    else if (v === undefined && keepUndefined) return "{{undefined}}";
    if(String(v).match(/^{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}$/)){
      v=v.replace(/^{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}$/g, '{{"{{$1}}"}}')
    }
    return v;
  }).replace(/(?<!\\)"{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}"/g, '$1').replace(/(?<!\\)"{{\\"{{(Infinity|NaN|-Infinity|undefined)}}\\"}}"/g, '"{{$1}}"'); 
}

const jsonFromStringRegex = /([{\[]{1}([,:{}\[\]0-9.\-+Eaeflnr-u \n\r\t]|".*?")+[}\]]{1}|["]{1}(([^(")]|\\")*)+(?<!\\)["]){1}/gis;

function jsonFromString(str) {
  const matches = str.match(jsonFromStringRegex);
  return matches.map((m) => JSONParse(m, true));
}

function jsonStringsFromString(str) {
  const matches = str.match(jsonFromStringRegex);
  return matches.map((m) => m);
}//returns the substrings that were detected as json without parsing them
//example parsing all the JSON from the text
console.log(jsonFromString(`some text {"val}ue": "something:some{thing"} and "teststri\\"n{g" some more other text [{"testa": 5, "testb": "t\\"\\"est6"}, {"testc": "1", "testd": "test45678"}, "teste", {"testf": {"testg": true, "testh": false}}] other extra added text {"somenumber": 14, "someothernumber": Infinity, "another number": -Infinity, "somenullvalue": null, "someundefinedvalue": undefined, "someNaNvalue": NaN} "somestring"`)); //it can detect the json correctly even if you have other brackets or escaped quotation marks (\") inside of the strings. 

//example stringifying all the JSON parsed from the text
console.log(JSONStringify(jsonFromString(`some text {"val}ue": "something:some{thing"} and "teststri\\"n{g" some more other text [{"testa": 5, "testb": "t\\"\\"est6"}, {"testc": "1", "testd": "test45678"}, "teste", {"testf": {"testg": true, "testh": false}}] other extra added text {"somenumber": 14, "someothernumber": Infinity, "another number": -Infinity, "somenullvalue": null, "someundefinedvalue": undefined, "someNaNvalue": NaN} "somestring"`)));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var a = JSON.parse('{"name":"John"}');
```

a ==> Object {name: "John"}

```
var b = [];
b.push(a);
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that there will be other content than "John" and other names than "name".

Comment: @FadiY can you add a sample string in your question that you want to parse?

Comment: @FadiY I dont understand what you are looking for? For the example string you gave the above code will work.

Comment: The "==>" doesn't seem to work for me. Are you sure it shouldn't be "=="?

Comment: @FadiY That is an example of how the output of variable a will be. It is not javascript code.

Comment: Lol... Lol... two more chara-