# jQuery - Using indexOf() with match()

Tags: jquery, regex, url, match, indexof

I am currently working on an user script made for YouTube using Firefoxs addon 'Greasemonkey' and came across a deadend.. Is it possible to check the url whether or not the url contains a specific string? I tried using indexOf() along with match() since I want it to check the string being case-insensitive..

My attempt with

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf(match(new RegExp("youtube.com/thumbnail?id=", "i"))) > -1) {
```

does not work however. I tried using contains() but it would return true as soon as the url has 'youtube' in it. Avoiding 'new RegExp' and only using match() does not work either, since I can't escape that forward slash in 'youtube.com/' with a backslash..

Comment: Why not
window.location.href.indexOf("youtube.com/thumbnail?id=") > -1

Comment: This is what my code originally was. But it's case sensitive. Meaning, using one uppercase letter would let the the if-statement return false..

Comment: you can look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

But is better lowecase to the href string ;)

window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube.com/thumbnail?id=")

Comment: I publish the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related question:
[Is there a version of JavaScript's String.indexOf() that allows for regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr)

But only for a case sensitive is more easy to do:

```
window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube.com/thumbnail?id=")
```