# Javascript find index of first non alphabetic char from certain position

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I want to finn the indexOF first non-aplhabetic char from a certain postion on

```
Example

abc4sss5gggg10
```

I wan to to get the position of 5 but to specify where I start searching

Comment: first non-alpha char it 4.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `char from a certain postion on`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Comment: You should really show us what you have tried.

Comment: Another very similar question with solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

Answer (score 6):

Use a combination of regular expressions and the substring function:

```
var str = "abc4sss5gggg10";
var indexToSearchFrom = 6;
var index = str.substring(indexToSearchFrom).search(/[^A-Za-z]/);
```

Comment: `[^A-Z]/i` can also be used. Less typing

Answer (score 2):

To get the index of first non-alpha char after the 4th position.

```
> 'abc4sss5gggg10'.replace(/^.{4}/, "").match(/[^a-z]/i)
[ '5',
  index: 3,
  input: 'sss5gggg10' ]
> 'abc4sss5gggg10'.replace(/^.{4}/, "").match(/[^a-z]/i)['index']
3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

I modified Mathijs Segers's code so it looks like this:

```
function StartSearching(str, startFrom) {
   for (var i = startFrom; i<str.length;i++) {
      if (!isNaN(str[i])) {
         return i;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider first this post here [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Then know that to find the first numeric value you have to use

```
var n = 2; // my starting position
var match = /[0-9]/.exec("abc4sss5gggg10".substring(n));
if (match) {
    alert("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Use `substring` to remove the first n characters

Comment: Yes but specify the position where to start the search from

Comment: How to find all non-aplphabetic charachters. This only finds digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your first thought might be regex, allthough those are heavy I'd probably go something like

```
getFirstNonAlpha(str) {
   for (var i = 0; i<str.length;i++) {
      if (!isNaN(str[i]) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

isNaN means isnotanumber so if it matches a number it'll return false and you can return the index.

Check which you need and which has a better speed if this is even an issue. Also this function won't help you with !@#$%^&*()_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "abc4sss5gggg10";

function searchIndex(index, strng) {
    var arr = strng.split("");
    for (var i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(arr[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
alert(searchIndex(4, str));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dm4g489y/)