# Negative Lookahead to find lat matched word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find last matched word in a sentence using regex. I searched for this functionality and found negative lookahead.

Ex: To find "foo" in "This foo is not same as the foo"

Here i need to find last matched "foo" 's index. For this I am using javascript search function with search(regex) where regex is foo(?!.*foo)

problem is that search is not returning correct index (it may be regex issue).This feature is same as chrome's find feature where up arrow finds previous match.So I want to know if i need to change my regex ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/272j97cd/), `28` looks correct to me.

Comment: thanks Wiktor again :) I was using substring in wrong way (substring to discard last previous matched word)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for that reason I simply suggested using `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`

Comment: yes but i need it to be case sensitive also and there might be some issues with localizations

Comment: @Bhuwan: What substring? Please *add the code you have into the question*.

Comment: You right @Bhuwan, for case sensitive here is an answer that could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

Comment: @wiktor suppose you have found first last matched word now when you want to find next previous you need to remove already found last matched word from sentence. So I was taking substring to remove last match from sentence

Comment: Good, but your question is off-topic now.

Comment: @wiktor yes anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find last matched "foo" 's index. You can use [String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
var lastIndex = 'This foo is not same as the foo'.lastIndexOf('foo');

console.log(lastIndex);
```

Comment: What if OP needs to find a `foo` that is only a whole word?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3eplj it is working fine.They are using match() javascript function but i need index of matched word so using search function

Comment: If `foo` is the only whole word the returned last index will be `0` instead of `-1` that returns if no found..