# Why doesn't this substring work in Chinese?

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, chinese-locale

Why doesn't this substring work in Chinese?
I'm getting the correct results for other languages but in Chinese I got an empty string.

```
    countryID = "奥地利（销售超过3万5千欧元）";
    countryID.substring(0, countryID.indexOf('(') - 1);

    countryID = "Austria (Sales > €35,000)";
    countryID.substring(0, countryID.indexOf('(') - 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(` and the chinese `（` are different unicode characters. You need to use `.indexOf('（')` for chinese characters.

Example:

```
<div id='d1'></div>
<script>
    var countryID = "奥地利（销售超过3万5千欧元）";
    document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML=countryID.indexOf('（');
</script>
```

Comment: can I change my substring and check both types? （ and ( ?

Comment: @Carlos Martins take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273789/is-there-a-version-of-javascripts-string-indexof-that-allows-for-regular-expr

Answer (score 1):

Because '(' is not in `countryID`, '（' and '(' are different characters, the first is chinese style bracket.

So maybe you can use:

`countryID.substring(0, countryID.indexOf('（') - 1);`

Comment: I can see that in the Chinese version I don't have the white space so I don't need the -1

Comment: Yes, it is. The key thing here is just that you need to pay some attention to some special Chinese symbols when you deal with the Chinese strings.