# Make from array string with length < 16

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have this array `["Brad", "came", "to", "dinner", "with", "us"]`

`Brad came to dinner with us` (27 chars > 16) so I need to split it into 2 strings:

```
Brad came to
dinner with us
```

Words cannot be sliced

```js
let inpt=["Brad", "came", "to", "dinner", "with", "us"]
op=[]
for(i of inpt) if (op.join('').length+i.length <16) {op.push(i)} else break
console.log(op.join(' '))
```

This return me first part but how can I get second and others if my input array(string) would be longer then 16+16+16....

Comment: Hi, perhaps start appending to a new list once the limit is reached?

Comment: Very similar question: [Split string at space after certain number of characters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836558/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string based on max character length, but keep words into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204155/splitting-a-string-based-on-max-character-length-but-keep-words-into-account)

Answer (score 3):

After joining by spaces, use a regular expression to match up to 16 characters, followed by a space or the end of the string:

```js
let inpt=["Brad", "came", "to", "dinner", "with", "us"];
const str = inpt.join(' ');
const matches = str.match(/.{1,16}(?: |$)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done via Array.reduce:

```js
let inpt=["Brad", "came", "to", "dinner", "with", "us"];

let out = inpt.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let l = acc.length;
  if (l === 0 || (acc[l - 1] + el).length > 15) {
    acc[l] = el;
  } else {
    acc[l - 1] += " " + el;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```