# Split a string by max characters length, word aware - but without capturing whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

The following regex ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58204391/3002584)) splits a string by characters length (e.g. 20 characters), while being word-aware ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JvHfMR/1)):

```
\b[\w\s]{20,}?(?=\s)|.+$
```

This means that if a word should be "cut" in the middle (based on the provided characters length) - then the whole word is taken instead:

```js
const str = "this is an input example of one sentence that contains a bit of words and must be split"

const substringMaxLength = 20;

const regex = new RegExp(`\\b[\\w\\s]{${substringMaxLength},}?(?=\\s)|.+$`, 'g');

const substrings = str.match(regex);

console.log(substrings);
```

However, as can be seen when running the snippet above, the leading whitespace is taken with each substring. Can it be ignored, so that we'll end up with this?

```
[
  "this is an input example",
  "of one sentence that",
  "contains a bit of words",
  "and must be split"
]
```

I tried adding either `[^\s]`, `(?:\s)`, `(?!\s)` everywhere, but just couldn't achieve it.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can require that every match starts with `\w` -- so for both options of your current regex:

```js
const str = "this is an input example of one sentence that contains a bit of words and must be split"

const substringMaxLength = 20;

const regex = new RegExp(`\\b\\w(?:[\\w\\s]{${substringMaxLength-1},}?(?=\\s)|.*$)`, 'g');

const substrings = str.match(regex);

console.log(substrings);
```

Comment: Seems like an ending `?` is needed to capture a single character.

Comment: It it is the last character of the input, it is not needed, as `.*$` can match an empty string, and if it is not the last character of the input, then certainly more should be captured (19 to go...) with the first option.

Comment: It's not working when the string contains some punctuation or special characters. Could you please also provide the solution for the following string?

`this is an input, example of-one sentence. that contains! a bit of words and; must be split.`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b((?:[^\\s]+\\s?){${substringMaxLength},}?)(?=\\s)|.+$`, 'g');
```

The regex uses a non-capturing group with a positive lookahead `(?=\s)` to prevent whitespace from being captured.
The lookahead checks if there is a whitespace after the group and if there is whitespace it returns a match.
The non-capturing group uses a positive look behind `(?<=\s)` to make sure that the group starts with whitespace.
`\b((?:[^\s]+\s?){20,}?)\b(?=\s)`

Regex Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern can start with a word character and the length minus 1.

The negative lookahead `(?!\S)` asserts a whitespace boundary to the right.

The alternative matches the rest of the line, and also starta with a word character.

```
\b\w(?:[\w\s]{19,}?(?!\S)|.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gf6e3k/1)

```js
const str = "this is an input example of one sentence that contains a bit of words and must be split"

const substringMaxLength = 20;

const regex = new RegExp(`\\b\\w(?:[\\w\\s]{${substringMaxLength-1},}?(?!\\S)|.*)`, 'g');

const substrings = str.match(regex);

console.log(substrings);
```